# 3Ds Max CAT animation

Tags: animation, layer, cat, 3dsmax

In character animation toolkit: I've created an animation in the absolute layer. How can I set rotation keyframes for the whole character?

Example: In my abs layer, I have created a dancing animation. Apart from this, I would like my character to be rotating around its own axis too. However when I select the whole character and try to rotate it, limbs don't rotate around character's axis, but rather around their own axes.

[image]

In CATMotion layer, it could be done by choosing a path node, but how can I achieve the same effect in the abs animation layer?

Answer (score 0):

The tool I was looking for is called a transform gizmo